# Java, sort arraylist by custom alpha order

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Let's say I have

```
arrayList<String> fruits
```

that contains

```
{"banana", "apple", "grape", "banana", "banana", "grape"}
```

I know how to sort these alphabetically by using a comparator (below) :

```
Collections.sort(fruits, new Comparator<Fruit>() {
        public int compare(Fruit o1, Fruit o2) {
            return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
        }
    });
```

However that would give me {"apple", "banana", "banana", "banana", "grape", "grape"}. How would I change this so I get all the bananas listed first, then apples, then grapes? Thanks!

Comment: What is the rule that defines that order?

Comment: If there's no rule that defines that order, maybe the fruit-types should be an enum with the proper order

Comment: are you sorting by flavors maybe??

Comment: Right, so the rule I made up myself is ['b','a','g'] or just ["banana","apple","grape"] is my sorting order.

Edit: I guess with the example I gave above the order doesn't make sense, but the way I will adapt it to my current project makes the most sense.

Comment: Simply define your order in your Comparator.

Comment: I assumed so @AndyThomas but I don't know how to define it and compare against it.

Comment: @JoshBeckwith - First, define the specific order you want. Second, implement Comparator.compare() to determine the order of the two Fruits provided, according to the order you've defined.

Comment: Is `ab` before `aa`?

Answer (score 3):

This might help get you started:

```
List<String> fruitsOrder = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"banana","apple","grape"});
Comparator<String> c = Comparator.comparingInt(str -> fruitsOrder.indexOf(str));
```

You could refine it further, by normalizing the case, and/or by using Comparator.thenComparing, to have a consistent order for fruits not in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You may first create your custom comparator like that :

```
public static class CustomFruitComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    Map<String, Integer> fruitsOrder;

    public CustomFruitComparator(Map<String, Integer> fruitsOrder) {
        this.fruitsOrder = fruitsOrder;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (fruitsOrder.get(o1) > fruitsOrder.get(o2))
            return 1;
        else if (fruitsOrder.get(o1) < fruitsOrder.get(o2))
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }

}
```

And then you can use it to sort your collection. In your case, you can do like that :

```
List<String> fruits = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"banana", "apple", "grape", "banana", "banana", "grape"});

    Map<String, Integer> fruitsOrder = new HashMap<>();
    fruitsOrder.put("banana", 1);
    fruitsOrder.put("apple", 2);
    fruitsOrder.put("grape", 3);

    Collections.sort(fruits, new CustomFruitComparator(fruitsOrder));
```